# Can I login to ASP.NET (with Forms Authentication) and then transfer that 'login' to a PHP application?

Tags: php, asp.net, session-cookies

Our website runs on ASP.NET v4 and users log in user Forms authentication.

We are considering purchasing a web application that will add to our services. The only problem is that this new website is written in PHP.

We would like users to login to our ASP.NET site and then navigate to the PHP site. The PHP site should notice that users are logged-in though. So we probably need to transfer the ASP.NET SessionID cookie and somehow use that to verify whether or not the user has been authorized.

Does this sound feasible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Theoretically yes. As you say you need to be able to translate the ASP.NET credentials into a form that the PHP site understands. I don't do PHP so I don't know whether this is actually possible or exactly how you'd do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surely possible, but you need some *dirty-coding* to do.

In fact, both ASP.NET and PHP `Session`s create a software layer that hides mechanisms used to perform session handling and validation.

You can simply define a common cookie between the two applications (make sure you sign it or store it in a common DB), then use your own custom logic to link an ASP.NET session to PHP.

Database is a great option. I would recommend you to define a custom session manager class in Web.config and have it write session data in common DB, from where PHP will load.

But I don't know how to write a custom PHP session manager. You might consider using custom PHP code on page init to initialize session basing on data found on DB.

So your application will be made of three things:

- ASP.NET part
- PHP part
- Common database

A simple usage scenario:

1. User performs login on ASP.NET
2. ASP.NET validates login, sets a cookie with known name and inserts a row in the database with cookie value (and possibly IP address for security)
3. User navigates PHP site transmitting the cookie
4. PHP checks cookie against table, and possibly initializes its own session

More complex designs could actually **share** session data between both PHP and ASP.NET using a single database table AND no local memory.

Answer (score 2):

It would work as long as your session information is stored in a database, and not flat-file (which is the PHP default). Basically the PHP script would be sent the Session ID via a cookie (just like ASP would), and then the PHP script will look up the corresponding session information in the database to get the user's information (e.g. username, privileges, etc.) to do its thing.

If you are not using database-driven sessions, then it gets a lot more complicated, since it's unlikely that ASP and PHP store their session information in a compatible flat-file format. The best thing to do in that situation might be to add an additional layer of your own on top of the session storage. For example, when the user is logged in on the ASP side of things, have some basic information that you need to know about the user save in a database (again that both ASP and PHP can access), and then write a unique key to a cookie. Have PHP read the cookie yourself, and look up the corresponding information in the database. This is essentially re-creating a basic version of sessions, so it would be best to switch to database-driven sessions in the first place, but it might be the only option available to you, depending on the specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how ASP.NET works but if you can place your session contents into a database table/flat file/roaming panda that is readable by both the PHP app and the ASP.NET app you can possibly transfer session data between the apps.

It would work similarly to a single sign on (SSO) system.

I forgot to add a reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php This function allows you to define custom session handlers within PHP. The only question is how much you can wrangle your new bought application to fit into your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion of this here:

[Detecting an expired asp.net session from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086013/detecting-an-expired-asp-net-session-from-php)

A couple of options they suggest:

1) Use ASP.NET's built-in Session State, and store the session in SQL Server, then, reading the session ID form the cookie in PHP, query SQL Server to see if the session is still alive.

2) I think they're saying: grab the ASP.NET Auth cookie in PHP, then make a request to the ASP.NET site (in the server PHP code), using it, and check to see if you get a redirect to login, for instance. I'm not sure this would work, because the MAC and IP are probably rolled up in the ASP.NET Auth cookie, but's it' kind of slick, if not insecure.