# Authentication in ASP.NET MVC which is in iframe

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have a question. How to check user authentication in MVC app, which is loaded in iFrame ? The main app, wchich presentig iframe was written in PHP. Users are logged in PHP app.

What can I do, to check is the user was authenticated, and check about his name, id or something what I'll map in my app.

I'm an author of MVC app, but not a PHP app. Of course I have a contact with the PHP teamt, so I can ask them to set something (object, marker, variable) when tehy call my MVC.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a common cookie between both the application or use a cookie created by php to know the user details and create one for your own asp.net mvc app. I have few similar link which may help

[Stackoverflow ASPNET-PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220885/can-i-login-to-asp-net-with-forms-authentication-and-then-transfer-that-login)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've wondering about cookies, but is it safe ? Or another way, is it safe enough to use it in the intranet ?

Comment: Yeah is it. After all, Almost all web applications use cookies. you can set expiration manually and can do a lot with it.